# Classify a table in lxml

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml, data-extraction

I am working with a large set of html documents.  One of my tasks is to extract all text from the documents.  I have gotten pretty far but now I am stumped because of the use of tables as containers / formatting structures for information that is not numeric in nature

My goal is to ignore - leave behind - not extract the 'table' if it is a table of numeric fields

I am getting ready to implement a brute rule based approach by taking a table and if more than some percentage of the td.text_content() can be classfied as digits I will decide that the table is a table of numeric values

I am wondering if someone else can suggest a better approach

Comment: Define "table of numeric fields" - all fields contain digits? Most fields can be parsed by `int()`? ...?

Comment: Yes not sure if most ( (>50%) is the right threshold but basically yes

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest contextual data parsing, such as implemented by [IBM's Watson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson_%28computer%29), but I suppose otherwise it is impossible to classify the table.  Could you post html examples of a numeric and a non-numeric table?  I'll update my answer when they are posted.